# Adding a WIF STS service to existing projects

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, wcf, wif

We have several websites that are set up in the following fashion:

Site1.Web - ASP.NET Web Project (.NET 4.0, WebForms)
Common.Core - Class Library Project (all db interaction)

The web project appears once for each site while the Common.Core project is shared among all sites.  We have a login form in the web project that, in order to authenticate, calls into the class library.  It would call off a code similar to below:

```
Common.Core.Authenticate auth = new Common.Core.Authenticate(conStr);
bool validLogin = auth.ValidateUser(userName, password);
if(validLogin)
{
    Common.Core.User = auth.GetCurrentUser();
}
```

The higher ups are pushing for a middle layer service/app tier and want to use a more elegant solution to handle single sign on.  Therefore, the decision has been made to use a WIF service to handle the login and validation.  Furthermore, we want to try to minimize the code that has to change in each web project, i.e. try to keep as many changes as possible in Common.Core.

I have seen a few samples that show how to add an STS reference to a web project.  This would work well in a scenario where the user validation isn't factored into another project like Core.Common.  However, in our scenario, how could we handle validation while still going through the common class library?

Ideally, I would like to add an STS reference to the Core.Common class library and replace the direct db logic (auth.ValidateUser above) with a call to an STS service.  However, is it even possible to do that?  Does the request have to initiate in the web project?  If so, is the STS reference required in both places?

Any tutorials or resources which follow the same web project -> class library -> STS service path would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would also recommend using WIF :-)

In a claims based scenario the authentication process is "reversed". Your app will not call anyone, it will receive the needed information from a trusted source (the STS).

The *"STS Reference"* is not a library reference. It's a logical connection between your app and the trusted source of security tokens. A token is the artifact your app will use to decide what to do with the user request.

I'd agree with @nzpcmad that it is likely you could entirely remove the calls to you Common.Core library. It might be useful to see what else can you do with it. What does the ***Common.Core.User*** object give you?

If it is just properties of a user (e.g. name, e-mail, roles, etc) it is very likely you could just create a new version that simply wraps the ***IPrincipal*** supplied byt WIF (a ***ClaimsPrincipal***).

For example (approx. no error handling, pseudo-code):

```
public User CurrentUser()
{
    var user = new User();
    var cu = HttpContext.Current.User as IClaimsPrincipal;
    user.Name = cu.Name;
    user.eMail = (cu.Identity as IClaimsIdentity).Claims.First( c=> c.ClaimType = "eMail" ).Value;
    return user;
}
```

As @nzpcmad says, you can use ADFS or some other STS. Your apps would not care.

Comment: Thanks for the info. The sample apps I've been working with have a trusted connection between the asp.net website and the STS site/service with no middle layer class library (Common.Core). The Common.Core.User class contains basic info stored in the db similar to your example above.  A new User class could easily be derived from IClaimsPrincipal.

Just to confirm then, for these existing sites, we'll have to establish the STS connection in the web app (not Common.Core) and we'll have to refactor/rewrite some of the GetCurrentUser() logic to derive from IClaimsPrincipal?

Comment: WIF does all the work for you. In a way WIF is the "middle layer" (en HTTPModule really). So, yes. At a high level that's what you'd do. Notice that you could still have Common.Core.User pulling up data about the user form a database. These would be ay additional information that is not supplied by the STS. In that case you wuld need to use some handle to correlate the data (e.g. an e-mail, a UID, etc)

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this is to FedUtil the ASP.NET project with an instance of ADFS. Essentially, authentication is now "outsourced" and you can simply remove the call to the core library from your app. ADFS is then setup to return whatever attributes the program needs for authorisation as claims. You may need to transform these claims attributes to whatever attributes are passed back to the common core in subsequent calls.

Or you could make the common core "claims aware" in the sense that it now recognizes "claims attributes" as opposed to "common core" attributes. This involves using different .NET classes - no hookup to ADFS is required.

Word of warning - your authentication seems to be all DB related. ADFS cannot authenticate against a DB. It can only authenticate against an instance of AD in the domain that ADFS is installed in (or other AD if trust relationship between AD).

If you want to authenticate against a DB you need a custom STS which is then federated with ADFS. See here: [Identity Server.](http://identityserver.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. ADFS wouldn't be an option for these sites, but a claims aware STS service/site would. I assume the STS trust has to be established with the web project (and not the Common.Core class library) as that is what is consuming the service.  Is that correct?